# Does increasing the number of readings/measurements increase the accuracy of the mean?

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

I understand that the accuracy of a reading/measurement is primarily dictated by systematic error and so the accuracy of your results can be improved by removing the source of the systematic error. However, I have heard mixed guidance on whether the accuracy of your readings/measurements can be improved by taking a mean of an increased number of readings/measurements.

My thinking is that if we imagine a situation where systematic errors have already been removed and so we are just left with random error, then a mean of more readings (admittedly with diminishing returns) will be a more accurate 'best estimate' of the accepted value than a mean with fewer readings as the randomness is more probable to cancel out with more readings.

Can anyone help give an explanation as to whether a mean of say 1000 readings/measurements is more accurate than a mean of say 5 readings/measurements?  Please assume the knowledge of a grade 12 or year 13/upper sixth student in your response if you can - thanks!

Comment: What you want to check is the standard deviation of your measurements. For correlated data it does go down with increasing test samples. You can read up on it on Wikipedia for basics.

Comment: does the standard deviation of the results not just tell you the uncertainty of your results and therefore not affect the mean and the accuracy?

Comment: There are some special constraints for more measurements to help: you have to be doing properly random sampling on a non-Markov system, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say you are trying to measure $x_{True}$. It is nature's true value of something of interest, measured in the $x$ coordinates.

You go out at take a bunch ($N$) of measurements, $x_i$, with systemic ($\sigma_{sys}$) and random error ($\delta x_i$).

You find the mean, $\bar x$, and standard deviation, $\sigma$, of your data set. From that, the standard error on the mean, or simply "standard error" is:

$$ \sigma_{\bar x} \approx \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt N} $$

Your final reported measurement of $x_{True}$ is:

$$ x_{True} \approx \bar x \pm \sigma_{\bar x} \pm \sigma_{sys} $$

where $\sigma_{sys}$ is the systematic error.

The *precision* of your measurement is given by:

$$ \sigma_{total} = \sqrt{\sigma_{\bar x}^2 + \sigma^2_{sys} }$$

That is clearly improved by increasing the number of measurements, though at some point, it is pointless because systematic error dominates the values (esp. because they are added in quadrature).

The *accuracy* of your measurement is given by:

$$ {\rm Accuracy} = |x_{True} - \bar x|$$

which not only does not depend on $N$, we can never know it, unless we know $x_{True}$.

Comment: Hi JEB. If i am measuring speed of a car where I don't know the speed. I have 5 different instruments. Each instrument gives me one reading e.g. S1,S2,...,S5 e.g. 35,37,37,38,37. The mean is 36.8, with stdev 0.96. let's say each instrument has an expected "error" or internal stdev of +/- 5%. How would I work out the overall standard error or overall error bounds?

Answer (score 2):

The standard error on the mean is taken as $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$ where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation and $N$ is the number of observations. Assuming your measurements are all equally “good” (same $\sigma$) doing more of them will indeed provide you with a better estimate of the mean (lower standard error).

As you mentioned, it also has diminishing returns, since it’s a square root dependence.

For more clarity: the standard error on the mean estimates how confident you can be that the value you obtain for the mean is correct. From it, you can obtain your confidence intervals in much the same way as you would with any other deviation.

Comment: so taking more readings increases the confidence but is the mean also more likely to get closer to the accepted value and hence be more accurate, provided the error is random in nature?

Comment: Isn’t that exactly what the confidence measures? The tighter your confidence interval is, the more confident you can be that your measurement is close to its “real” value. Obviously there’s always a chance of your value not being accurate due to a long string of “unlucky” measurements. You could, for example, have a very lucky first 5 measurements, and the following 95 could be very unlucky, drawing you further from the accurate value. Of course this becomes vanishingly unlikely the more measurements you do.

Comment: sorry my last response wasn't clear.  i meant the calculated value of the mean will change every time a new data point is introduced into the calculation, will the mean therefore not get closer to the accepted value the more reading we take?  i can see from your previous response that the confidence of the mean increases with more data points and that makes sense to me now, it's just this last point that i'm still not quite clear on

Comment: Yes, it’s what I’m covering in the second part of the comment. Statistically speaking, it will (eventually, as $N \to \infty$) get closer. In practice, however, it cannot be guaranteed, especially if the increase in the number of measurements is small, such as 5 vs 8).

Comment: The Bayesian flame war, on one side, corrects this to: the error estimate is the probability that another measurement will give you the same **estimate** of the mean,  rather than the probability that you correctly measured the mean value of the ensemble.

Comment: I feel that a Bayesian approach doesn’t really comply with the request to “assume the knowledge of a grade 12 or year 13/upper sixth student in your response if you can”.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when you calculate the mean and an error (let us say standard deviation), you assume that your data is normally distributed. There is an original statistics which represents the system or the events that you measure here. However, we cannot know the actual distribution, our best effort can be mean of the measurements/readings that we get. Mean is one of the best estimates which we can calculate for a distribution, and standard deviation is another. Notice that we calculate the sample mean and sample standard deviation since we cannot have the actual population (in reality we have a small portion of data). For the accuracy of the mean, on the other hand, we need the calculate the standard error of the mean.

Let us examine the formula for the mean, the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) and the [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error), directly quote from wikipedia.

The mean is the following;

> $\overline{x}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=0}^{N}x_{i}$

the standard devation is

> $s=\sqrt{ \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=0}^{N}(x_{i}-\overline{x})^{2}  }$

and the standard error is

> $\sigma_{\overline{x}} \approx \frac{s}{\sqrt{N}}$

where $N$ is the number of readings/measurements.

Notice that there is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ in the standard error formula. The standard error is decreasing with the square root of the number of readings/measurements. This means that when you have large number of readings/measurements, the estimation of the mean is getting closer to the actual mean of the distribution since all you have is sample mean.

Therefore, when you have 1000 readings/measurements instead of 5 readings/measurements, the error of your estimate of the mean is smaller.